# calling setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds on multiple views with the same background gives inconsistent sizes

Tags: android, drawable

I've got a `LinearLayout` with two `EditText` descendants (not direct children). I call `EditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.xyz,0)` on each to put a drawable (the same drawable) on the right side of each of the `EditText`s. The two edit texts are identical, except for their order in the `ListView`. However, the size of the drawable in the first `EditText` becomes larger than the second after adding the drawables. Specifically, the first `EditText` resizes to accomodate the intrinsic size of the drawable, whereas the second `EditText` does not (although it does grow some small amount).

Why do two of the same drawables appear differently in the two near-identical views?

Also, I could solve this problem by figuring how to make the drawable not force the `EditText to resize`. As you can see, I've followed the directions at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList regarding making the background scale, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

the code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView 
        style="@style/fieldLabel"
        android:text="phone number"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contactPhoneField" 
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        style="@style/editableField"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView 
        style="@style/fieldLabel"
        android:text="e-mail address"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contactEmailField" 
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        style="@style/editableField"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the drawable:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient 
                android:startColor="#FFD060" 
                android:endColor="#FFBB33"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp"
                android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF8800"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/warn"/><!-- a 35x35 px png which is taller than the native height of an EditText-->
</layer-list>
```

then at some point I call:

```
contactPhoneField.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.error_background, 0);
contactEmailField.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.error_background, 0);
```

Additionally, every subsequent time I call `EditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.xyz,0)` (after calling it the first time) causes first `EditText`'s size to toggle between matching the 2nd `EditText` and matching the drawable size!