# Custom Layout doesn't resize children when used as ListView items

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom aggregate `View` that I'm trying to derive from `RelativeLayout` like so:

```
public class CheckableView extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {

TextView        mTextView;
boolean         mIsChecked = false;
int             mId = 0;

public CheckableView(
        Context context, 
        AttributeSet attrs, 
        int defStyle,
        int resource, 
        int textViewResourceId) throws Exception {

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (inflater != null) {
        inflater.inflate(resource, this);
        this.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(textViewResourceId);
        if (mTextView == null) {
            throw new Exception("The specified TextView resource Id was not found.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

The `resource` param is the `id` of a layout I want this `CheckableView` to aggregate and `textViewResourceId` is the id of the `TextView` that I was to graphically indicate `checked` status on (by drawing a checkmark against it)

This xml is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemslist_categoryName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/category_details_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addedit_category_check"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addedit_category_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addedit_category_price_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to use this custom view as each row of a particular `ListView` so elsewhere in a `ListView` adapter's `getView`, I do the following:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CheckableView view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            try {
                view = new CheckableView(getContext(), 
                                                   null, 
                                                   0, 
                                                   R.layout.addedit_group_budget, 
                                                   R.id.addedit_category_check);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            view = (CheckableView) convertView;
        }

        ...
        return view;
    }
```

Every row of the `ListView` has texts of differing lengths. When the view is first created, every thing seems to be fine, but when views start to get recycled (i.e. when I scroll up/down). The `TextViews` don't seem to resize to fit the size of the text even though I have `wrap_content` specified for the width.

What could I be missing? Example screen shot below. Notice that some of the text is ellipsized, even though there's clearly room for more text.

[image: Text Ellipses even though there is more room]

If I delete `implements Checkable` from the class definition, things work as expected indicating this has something to do with it.

Comment: Found a thread that comes pretty close - http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout. Doesn't work for me though. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out that the actual culprit is the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` API which I was making on one of TextView's. Calling this API seems to wreck havoc on the measurements of the View's within the parent layout. This issue is articulated beautifully @  [calling setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds on multiple views with the same background gives inconsistent sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592621/calling-setcompounddrawableswithintrinsicbounds-on-multiple-views-with-the-same)

I was able to work around the problem by using an ImageView in which I set the appropriate icon to indicate "checked" state.